# How can I most easily replace 'Track X' with track information on a website?

Tags: music

I don't have the CD on hand; see the track information on [Deutsche Grammaphon's website](https://www.deutschegrammophon.com/en/cat/4717472). It's obviously too unproductive to copy the track information from DG and paste it to each Track, even with free file renaming software like [Advanced Rename](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/).

[image]

Comment: Where do you see that information? Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: @harrymc Do you see my first embedded link to Deutsche Grammaphon's website? Let me know if not, and I'll post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a product to automatically identify and add metadata
and then rename audio file according to the metadata, you could use for example
the free
[MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/)
available for Windows, Linux or Mac OS X.

For a review, see the article
[How to master your music metadata (Part 1)](https://www.techhive.com/article/3192777/how-to-master-your-music-metadata-part-1.html).

[image]

For other free products, see the article
[The 5 Best Free MP3 Tag Editors](https://www.lifewire.com/free-tools-for-editing-song-information-2438490)
(the WMA format is also supported).

Answer (score 0):

Try metatogger:

**Metatogger allows correcting or completing audio files tags. It comes with features that allow:**

```
manual tags editing or with C# scripts;
retrieve tags from file name or paths;
rename files with tags content;
look after duplicate audio files;
organize files according to tags (copy, move, symbolic link);
retrieve tags in a local database of 1.5 million public records;
retrieve covers and lyrics from Internet;
identify files using acoustic fingerprinting technology;
easily clean unwanted tags.
```

**Metatogger works with Ogg Vorbis, FLAC, M4A (AAC and ALAC) and WMA.**

https://www.luminescence-software.org/en/metatogger.html

NOTE: This is a software request question which is technically "off topic" on this website. The only reason it hasn't been closed is the bounty.